# AS3 using base class object to create instance of extended class

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a custom class that extends `MovieClip`. The idea is that it allows for storing extra variables and information about the `MovieClip`.

```
public class MapObject extends MovieClip
{
    private var cellX:int;
    private var cellY:int;

    public function MapObject()
    {
    }
 }
```

I have several `MovieClips` (.swf files) that I load at runtime. The problem is, how can I make these MovieClip objects actually become `MapObject` objects?

I've tried :

```
var mapObject:MapObject = myMovieClip as MapObject;
```

but it gives `null`

PS. I know you can add variables dynamically to MovieClips, but I don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the class hierarchy without changing the code. You would have to go in each class definitions to change the parent class to `MapObject` instead of `MovieClip`.

There is an easy and clean solution which consists in using a decorator:

```
public class MapObject {

    private var mc:MovieClip;
    private var cellX:int;
    private var cellY:int;

    public class MapObject(mc:MovieClip) {
        this.mc = mc;
    }

    public function get movieClip():MovieClip {
        return mc;
    }
}
...

var wrapper:MapObject = new MapObject(new MyMovieClip());
...

container.addChild(wrapper.movieClip);
```

It's a wrapper that takes an instance of another class (in your case MovieClip) to add functionality. It's very powerful because you don't have to go and change each of your subclasses any time you change `MapObject`. This principle is called [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

In your case, all methods and properties of `MovieClip` are public so you would just write `mc.play()` instead of `this.play()`.

See the [details about the Decorator design pattern](http://www.as3dp.com/2009/04/actionscript-30-easy-and-practical-decorator-design-pattern/).

Comment: However, you can't get a reference to the information in the wrapper by looking at the instance on the stage. So another solution is to have the mc use a base class that implements an interface that has a property pointing to a separate object with the cellX and cellY, or use a dictionary to look up the wrapper based on the movieclip.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. There is your solution or storing all wrappers - although it might become inefficient because it sort of duplicates what the display list.